# How to know all info DHCP returns?

Tags: networking, dhcp

If I am correct, DHCP also returns the SNTP address. Is there a command in CMD (DOS...) that is like a "test" DHCP, meaning, that I can run it and will tell me everything that DHCP is returning? The IP address, the gateway address, the SNTP address, etc.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the SNTP address is configured in your dhcp server.

you can install wireshark and debug the dhcp packets and look for option 4 (thats the option for SNTP server).

this is not possible to see with dos

greetings

Comment: I wanted to avoid installing wireshark, but I see there's no alternative. Thanks a lot.